# Is there a way to query or modify the history of a single tab with a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking through the [Chrome Extension API documentation about `chrome.history`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html), and I can't seem to find a way to query or modify the history of a *single tab*. That is to say, the back/forward menu contents of a tab. Everything in the docs seems to treat Chrome's history as if it was one large amalgam.

So, is there a way to query or modify Chrome history on a tab-by-tab basis? If so, how?

Comment: Just guessing here without any chrome extension development experience, but how about injecting javascript into the tab of your choice and get to the history of the tab in the injected code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. Jasper's suggestion is valid though, injecting a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) would allow access to the history of the tab.

Comment: Even if you used a content script, the `window.history` object only holds the length of the history, not the URLs that were visited.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and decided to programmatically simulate using the right-click button on the back arrow. I just recently set up a keyboard shortcut for that.

The drawback of this method is that it only works for a fixed window size and maybe needs to be set up again every time we use a different computer.